# How to rollback MongoDB request after the RequestStart() method?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using **MongoDB C# Driver** (official form 10gen), I'm doing the following code:

```
using (database.RequestStart()) {    
    collection.Save(object);    
}
```

I would want to know how to stop the request and rollback the existing performed operations after the `RequestStart()`method.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I searched across the web and found these methods only increase connection performance, but doesn't stores any operation.

The concept of *MongoDB* operations are performed with a single-by-single operation.

The `RequestStart()` method only gets the current connection state for reusing it. If no existing connection are open, it opens a new connection and tell to driver that all the following operations - until the `RequestDone()` method is called - will use the current opened connection.

In other side, *MongoDB* have the capability to do [***two-phase commits***](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/#phase-commits-step-1), which are, in our "SQL concept", a **transaction-like pattern**. In this case, the *MongoDB C# Driver* needs to implement this pattern, or we can do it ourselves developing command adapters.

Comment: MongoDB does NOT have a multi-phase commits or any other sort of transactions in SQL sense.  What you linked to is an example of the *application* implementing transactional semantics.  None of it would be done natively in the DB layer.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong saying "multi-phase", but the article is clear, the example is not for an application, is for direct engine developing, using a pattern. The title is *"Perform two-phase commits"* and is a capability of MongoDB. I edited the answer for no more mistakes about FEATURE and PATTERN.

Comment: I think you still misunderstand - MongoDB C# driver will never implement support for transactions.  They can only be performed by the application itself.

Comment: I am really trying to agree with you, but, thinking MongoDB C# Driver is not only a engine for connect with MongoDB, but also a framework for develop any application on the main database core, I really believe this pattern can be implemented in later versions. If it would not, we can do it ourselves, like I said before.

Comment: Is this available in MongoDB C# Driver 2.2?